# How can I subindex a multiway array with vector that preserves blanks

Tags: r

As a minimal example lets consider the following multiway array (a):

```
a = as.table(array(c(1:8), dim=c(2,2,2)))
```

For this array manual subindicing is easy, e.g.

`a[1,,]` (a 2 x 2 matrix that comply with dimension one being in state 1 (A))

My question is now; how can I do the same thing with a vector that preserves blanks, e.g. something like `c(1,,)`.

Note that I need to define which dimentions are left blank (dynamically) based on the observed variables in an instance; My initial thought was a generic cha. vector b=c("","","") , where I could replace variable 1 with 1 if it was observed as in state 1, e.g. b[1]="1", but, first of all, I do not know how to use this vector for indicing a["b"], or whether there is a better way of doing this.

I need this dynamic indicing, because I want to update parts of the table as I receive evidence (information == counts)

Thank you very much in advance!

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: Note that I need to define which dimentions are left blank (dynamically) based on the observed variables in an instance; My initial thought was a generic cha. vector b=c("","","") , where I could replace variable 1 with 1 if it was observed as in state 1, e.g. b[1]="1", but, first of all, I do not know how to use this vector for indicing a["b"], or whether there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: How flexible do you want this indexing to be?  I.e., what are the possible ways you would want to index your array?

Comment: Thanks, I need to be able to address any combination: a[1,1,1], a[1,,], a[,,1], a[1,,1] etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty way of solving it:

data:

```
a = as.table(array(c(1:8), dim=c(2,2,2)))
```

Your dynamic indices should be a text: (that's a new question of how you get your condition into a string like `index`, `index2`)

```
index  = "1,,"
index2 = ",2,"
```

function:

```
crazyIndexing <- function(obj, index) {
    stringExpr = paste0(obj, "[",index,"]")
    return(eval(parse(text=stringExpr)))
}
```

call your function: (see how it does the same!)

```
a[1,,]
crazyIndexing("a",index)

a[,2,]
crazyIndexing("a",index2)
```

---

please note:

```
b=c("","",""); b[1]="1"
index = paste0(b, collapse = ",")
#[1] "1,,"
```

---

You can of course change your function accordingly:

```
crazyIndexing2 <- function(obj, obj2, index) {
    stringExpr = paste0(obj ,"[",index,"]", "<-", obj, "[",index,"]", "+", obj2)
    eval(parse(text=stringExpr))
    return( get(obj) )
}

a = as.table(array(c(1:8), dim=c(2,2,2)))

aa = a[,2,]

aopt = crazyIndexing2("a","aa","1,,")
```

Now you have all the tools.

Comment: Hi again, using this idea; how can I update a subtable dynamically, e.g. a[1,,] = a[1,,] + aa, where aa is of the same size as a[1,,]? This is really my problem...?

Comment: Dear Andre, thank you for your responses; I definitely think it does - I just keep thinking that there must be some buildin routine as well, given that this is a pretty common problem? But thank you very much for your time - I will prove test your solutions tomorrow on a real problem. Best, Sebastian

Comment: A final question - crazyIndexing2 will change a in the global; what should be changed to be able to change it in the local environment, and then use the function to return aopt, like aopt = crazyIndexing2("a","aa","1,,")?

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much; this definitely solbes my problem. Best, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
while (evidence) {
    idx <- lapply(dim(a), function (dimsize) 1:dimsize)
    ## update `idx` according to `evidence`, e.g.,
    ## if you want to do `a[1,,2]`
    idx[[1]] <- 1
    idx[[3]] <- 2
    do.call(`[`, c(list(a), idx))
    ## if you want to do `a[1,,2] <- c(20, 30)`
    a <- do.call(`[<-`, c(list(a), idx, list(value=c(20, 30))))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I want to use this scheme to recursively update a, like a[1,,] = a[1,,] + aa; how would I do it?

Comment: @SebastianGlavind: I added an example.